# ExtJs View with multiple style (scss) for each language

Tags: extjs, extjs7

My ExtJs application has to be multilingual.

On the login page, I asked the user to select the language from a dropdown list.

the current structure of my application files as the following

```
[app]
  [classic]
    [src]
      [view]
        [customers]
          customerController.js
          customerView.js
          customerView.scss
```

**How can I have multiple `scss` files for the same view ?**

For example `customerView.scss` to be a general file loaded all the time,  `customerView.en.scss` to be English specific, only when the user selects **English** on the login page, and `customerView.es.scss` only when the user selects **Spanish** on the login page

**Or is there any better idea?**

Answer (score 0):

The easeiest way might be to add a class to the viewport:

```
Ext.getBody().addCls('language-en')
```

Inside your scss files you add:

```
.language-en {
    .customer-view {
    }
}

.language-de {
    .customer-view {
    }
}
```

Otherwise you have to get into the `build.xml` and into the fashion builder.

In the fashion builder you have to rearrange the build.